# Is it correct, that JUnit is not working with JSF on GlassFish v3, without instantiating an ejb container?

Tags: junit, ejb-3.0, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'am developing a web-app for my thesis. Now I'm on that part, where I want to run automated tests on that web-app. The problem is, that I'm not able to run this tests. Stacjtrace says that he could not find classes which are needen from the class that I want to test.

I've debugged and looked in NetBeans which classes are loaded. And it seems that only the class, which I test was loaded. Someone told me, that I must run an embedded GlassFish.

Thanks in advance

```
Testcase: testGetInstance(org.iav.io.IOFacadeTest):        Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.iav.io.IOFacade.<init>(IOFacade.java:32)
        at org.iav.io.IOFacade.getInstance(IOFacade.java:47)
        at org.iav.io.IOFacadeTest.testGetInstance(IOFacadeTest.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.iav.io.LicenseListFileBean.<clinit>(LicenseListFileBean.java:47)


Testcase: testGetPoolSize(org.iav.io.IOFacadeTest):        Caused an ERROR
Could not initialize class org.iav.io.LicenseListFileBean
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.iav.io.LicenseListFileBean
        at org.iav.io.IOFacade.<init>(IOFacade.java:32)
        at org.iav.io.IOFacadeTest.testGetPoolSize(IOFacadeTest.java:63)
```

The class IOFacade:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class IOFacade extends Observable {

    private static IOFacade instance;
    private UserListFileBean userListFileBean;
    private LicenseListFileBean licenseListFileBean;
    private FileAccessorBean fileAccessorBean;

    /**
     * Constructor for this class. Initializing also dependent classes.
     * Encapsulates IO-Subsystem from beeing direct accessed.
     */
    public IOFacade() {
        licenseListFileBean = LicenseListFileBean.getInstance();
        userListFileBean = UserListFileBean.getInstance();
        fileAccessorBean = FileAccessorBean.getInstance();
        /** Registering this instance at fileAccessorBean to be notified if list
         * has changed.
         */
        addObserver(fileAccessorBean);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a unit test involves only the class you are testing.  You have to mock out the container classes for your unit test.

If what you are after is an integration or systems test, which tests how your class interacts with it's environment, then you will need to run your application in an embedded environment.  Check out [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian), it provides a simple easy to use way to manage your embedded test environment.  Works with Glassfish 3.0.1, JBoss, and some other containers.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be really easy to use. Will give it a try.

Comment: @adem.caliskan Right on!  Arquillian is great.  If it works for you, don't forget to accept this answer.